# Is it possible to move data between databases on a PL SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm working on a database whose data needs fixing after server falling down.

I'll do the data fixing on a auxiliar MariaDb database before moving the info to the final database.

Is it possible to store a procedure on either the databases to read from the auxiliar, (make some check) and inserting into the final one?

Comment: MariaDB does not support PL/SQL (it's specific to the Oracle database) - which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: Maybe I'm writing the code on PL/SQL and it gets sintax-translated to mysql scripting languaje I'm pretty sure I work with mariadb. I use dbeaver as tool.

Comment: It looks like it should be possible to connect to a MariaDB instance via ODBC and the Oracle Heterogenous Gateway, e.g. https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mariadb-odbc-oracle-hs.rst Maybe this is more of a [DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com) though. From a PL/SQL perspective, if it can access the tables it should be fine, subject to any limitations the interface may have.